# how to install private repo using glide golang

Tags: go, package-managers, glide-golang

I am using `glide` as package management for my golang project. I can't able to get private repositories using `glide get bezos.gitlab.com/gomock`.

It asks username & password even i give correct credentials, it ended up throwing error. Please suggest any idea.

Comment: Are you using git over ssh with keys?

Comment: @JimB Yes, I am using git over ssh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is nothing do with `glide` or any other package management tools. You have to set create and set gitlab access token in your git http.extraheader.

Go to your gitlab **settings -> access token** and create new access token, make sure to copy the token it available only once.

Then set these git global variables, now you can install private repositories using `glide`, `go get`, `godep`, etc.

> git config --global http.extraheader "PRIVATE-TOKEN: YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
>
> git config --global url."git@bezos.gitlab.com:".insteadOf "https://bezos.gitlab.com/"

Comment: Why are you setting the http header if you're configuring it to always use ssh?

Comment: @JimB When we try to install packages using `go get github.com/nsqio/go-nsq` it makes https call to get the package. That's why it always prompt username and password while trying to download. 
So that when you set `--global url` to refer as `git@path-to-clone` instead of  `https://path-to-clone`. To get access to the repo, we are setting `http.extraheader private-token` .